# How can I make multiple ajax in one function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My array for add query... The Addquery works for the first table (tb_empgrocery) but the Savequery doesn't work for the second table (tb_empgroc_master).

```
function saveme(){
    var data = new Array();
    $('#cLoanOut2 > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
        var nodes = $(this).children();
        var itemno = nodes[0].innerHTML,
        qty = nodes[2].innerHTML,
        unitprc = nodes[3].innerHTML,
        amt = nodes[4].innerHTML;
        data.push({
            name: "itemno[]",
            value: itemno
        },{
            name: "qty[]",
            value: qty
        },{
            name: "unitprc[]",
            value: unitprc
        },{
            name: "amt[]",
            value: amt
        });
    });
            return data;
}
```

This is my function and I want to call the Save function in my PHP file. Can I do 2 ajax call in one function? The first ajax call works fine on the first table but the 2nd ajax call can't receive the data to the 2nd table. My 1st table is tb_emgrocery and the other one is tb_empgroc_master

```
$('#OKBtn2').click(function(){
    $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
    var itemid = $('#main-form2 .active').attr('id'),
    qty = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(2)').text(),
    unit_price = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(3)').text(),
    amount = $('#main-form2 #'+itemid+' td:eq(4)').text();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?","No","Yes",function(r){
        if(r) {
        var itemno = $('#itemNo').val();
        var data = saveme();
            data.push({
                name: "todo",
                value: "Add"
            });
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({  
                url : url,
                type : "POST",
                async : false,
                data : data,
                success:function(result){
                    bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
                });
                updateTable();
                }
            });   
        } else {

        }
    });
             //Am I doing right here?
             $.ajax({  
             url : url,
             type : "POST",
             async : false,
             data : {
                 todo:"Save"
                 }
             });   
});
```

This is my PHP file

```
case "Add":
            $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
            $qty = $_POST['qty'];
            $unitprc = $_POST['unitprc'];
            $amt = $_POST['amt'];
            $coopmemid = $_SESSION['kiosk']['is_coopmemID_kiosk'];
            for($x=0; $x<count($itemno); $x++) {
                $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgrocery (coopmemID , date_ordered, item_no, qty_ordered, unit_price, amount) 
                        VALUES ('$coopmemid',(NOW()),'$itemno[$x]','$qty[$x]','$unitprc[$x]','$amt[$x]')";
                mysql_query($Addquery, $con);
            }
        break;
        case "Save":
        if(isset($_POST['Add'])){
                    $Addquery = "INSERT INTO tb_empgroc_master (date_ordered) VALUES ((NOW()))";
                    mysql_query($Addquery, $con);
                    }
        break;
```

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: Are you wanting to run something after all calls have been made, or are you wanting to do make the second call after the first for a reason?

Comment: the 2nd call.. The first call is correct @Popnoodles

Answer (score 1):

Yes after getting response of first ajax call you can call another ajax.you can do like following:

```
$.ajax({  
    url : url,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    data : data,
    success:function(result){
        bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
        });
        updateTable();
        //here you can call another ajax request
    }
});
```

Full Code:

```
$.ajax({  
    url : url,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    data : data,
    success:function(result){
        bootbox.alert('Ordered',function(){
        });
        updateTable();
        //here you can call another ajax request
        //Am I doing right here?
        $.ajax({  
            url : url,
            type : "POST",
            async : false,
            data : {
                todo:"Save"
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

If you want to pass `todo` in first ajax call. Use following:

```
data.push({
            name: "todo",
            value: "Add"
            todo: "Save"
        });
```

Comment: Can I call todo: "Save" on the first call so that i will have only one ajax call by merging save to the first one?

Comment: Yes sure you can pass `todo` in first ajax call for avoiding multiple request.

Comment: data: data,
todo: "Save",

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: Thank you... I appreciate your help but still won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Place them inside of the `success:` of the one it relies on.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com',
    data: {name: 'your name'},
    dataType: 'post',
    success: function(data){

        // do stuff

        // call next ajax function
        $.ajax({ next ajax });
    }
});
```

repeat  multiple levels of ajax calls inside each ajax success.